# How does one force portrait launch for an otherwise universally-oriented app?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, uistoryboard

My universal app allows some view controllers to be in landscape, but not the first screen. The launch image looks like the first screen; it needs to be in portrait when running on iPhone. On iPad, all orientations are acceptable. How can this be handled?

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
```

can't be used for the View Controller for the launch storyboard.

Comment: Just put launch image in portrait mode only and handle the rest in supportedInterfaceOrientations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "Initial interface orientation" key to your projects plist. Set the value to "Portrait (bottom home button)" or some other desired value. Go to the "General" tab of your project file and deselect the device orientations. In your view controllers override `supportedInterfaceOrientations`

---

***This was a great start! Here's what else was needed… – Jessy***

`Initial interface orientation` is the prettified name of the string key `UIInterfaceOrientation`. The [Creating and Editing an Information Property List File](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW9) documentation tells us that we would need an iPhone-specific entry, like this:

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation~iphone</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>,
```

Because that is the default, specifying it is not necessary. However, it is necessary to specify all four values for the `Supported interface orientations (iPad)` key, which is the prettified version of `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad`. [`UIInterfaceOrientation` is ignored if the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` key is present](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW13), so the `~ipad` part must be present.

Comment: Did you try it? Because this really only applies to the iPad and iPhone 6 plus, those were the devices I tested.

Comment: My app runs only on the iPhone, and I want it to launch in portrait. I tried setting UIInterfaceOrientation to portrait and UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone to all three (portrait, landscape left, landscape right). But it still launches in landscape on iPhone 7 Plus, if the home screen was in landscape before the app was launched. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Agreed, this answer is incorrect. If device is held landscape at launch, the launch screen will still be displayed landscape. (even doing what's mentioned in this answer). We should note that we have to add "all but upside down" to UISupportedInterfaceOrientations.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!